# Zoomable div in jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there a possibiity that a `div` can be made *zoomable*, using jQueryMobile library?

In it, the header and footer of the page should remain fixed, while the user should be able to interact ( zoom and pan, through gestures as it's a page for mobile ) only the central part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

A zoomable div can be implemented using hammer library.
more details here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27572427/1158763