# Visual Studio 2017 Apache Cordova Project with Zoom

Tags: zooming, visual-studio-cordova, pinchzoom

I have created a small test application using Visual Studio 2017, choosing the "Blank App (Apache Cordova)" option the JavaScript grouping. I have successfully built my application but as I dig further into capabilities, I am wondering how to implement zoom on android.  I simply have text on the screen that I want the user to be able to zoom on double tap or pinch. I have done a lot of google searches and stack overflow searches on the subject and I haven't been successful yet. I have tested things such as using meta tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

But simple things like that hasn't worked. I have also tried implementing plugins such as Hammer.js to achieve my goals but haven't been successful yet.  Can someone help out?  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Currently using javascript - [hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/) - is the only supported method of adding pinch zooming. Apache cordova is nothing more than a very basic web browser that lacks things like this. 
The hammer.js package can be used add that functionality to it.

http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-pinch/

To implement it, follow the example given in this post -> [Pinch to zoom using Hammer.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011099/pinch-to-zoom-using-hammer-js)

```
function hammerIt(elm) {
    hammertime = new Hammer(elm, {});
    hammertime.get('pinch').set({
        enable: true
    });
    var posX = 0,
        posY = 0,
        scale = 1,
        last_scale = 1,
        last_posX = 0,
        last_posY = 0,
        max_pos_x = 0,
        max_pos_y = 0,
        transform = "",
        el = elm;

    hammertime.on('doubletap pan pinch panend pinchend', function(ev) {
        if (ev.type == "doubletap") {
            transform =
                "translate3d(0, 0, 0) " +
                "scale3d(2, 2, 1) ";
            scale = 2;
            last_scale = 2;
            try {
                if (window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('-webkit-transform').toString() != "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)") {
                    transform =
                        "translate3d(0, 0, 0) " +
                        "scale3d(1, 1, 1) ";
                    scale = 1;
                    last_scale = 1;
                }
            } catch (err) {}
            el.style.webkitTransform = transform;
            transform = "";
        }

        //pan    
        if (scale != 1) {
            posX = last_posX + ev.deltaX;
            posY = last_posY + ev.deltaY;
            max_pos_x = Math.ceil((scale - 1) * el.clientWidth / 2);
            max_pos_y = Math.ceil((scale - 1) * el.clientHeight / 2);
            if (posX > max_pos_x) {
                posX = max_pos_x;
            }
            if (posX < -max_pos_x) {
                posX = -max_pos_x;
            }
            if (posY > max_pos_y) {
                posY = max_pos_y;
            }
            if (posY < -max_pos_y) {
                posY = -max_pos_y;
            }
        }


        //pinch
        if (ev.type == "pinch") {
            scale = Math.max(.999, Math.min(last_scale * (ev.scale), 4));
        }
        if(ev.type == "pinchend"){last_scale = scale;}

        //panend
        if(ev.type == "panend"){
            last_posX = posX < max_pos_x ? posX : max_pos_x;
            last_posY = posY < max_pos_y ? posY : max_pos_y;
        }

        if (scale != 1) {
            transform =
                "translate3d(" + posX + "px," + posY + "px, 0) " +
                "scale3d(" + scale + ", " + scale + ", 1)";
        }

        if (transform) {
            el.style.webkitTransform = transform;
        }
    });
}
```

> To implement just call it with
>   hammerIt(document.getElementById("elementId")); after the element has
>   loaded. You can call this on as many elements as you like.